# Rails/Angular: How to implement internal and external REST/JSON APIs in same app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm planning on implementing a single-page application in Rails/AngularJS which also has some pieces that are exposed as a "public" API. My question is, what's the best way to architect the two APIs in such an application? E.g. Is it wise to have them both housed/versioned in the same namespace, or should they be kept separate somehow?

This is relatively new territory for me, but at first blush it seems like providing a single API covering both internal and external needs, then parsing up which pieces are available via some kind of authorization system based on the provided token would be the best way of going about this.

Is this the right direction, or would you recommend some other path?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I will give you my opinion.

CAVEAT: I'm not a rails guy so I'm coming at this from nodejs/expressjs land.

There are many ways to skin this cat, but I'll just say that you are headed in the right direction. if you want to look at a very opinionated way to do things (and one people might hate) in node, see this: https://github.com/DaftMonk/fullstack-demo/blob/master/server/api/user/index.js. here you see this bit:

```
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.index);
router.delete('/:id', auth.hasRole('admin'), controller.destroy);
router.get('/me', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.me);
router.put('/:id/password', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.changePassword);
router.get('/:id', auth.isAuthenticated(), controller.show);
router.post('/', controller.create);
```

these routes correspond to calls to http:/serverurl/api/user/ etc. obviously, these are all checking authentication, but you could easily create a resource route that didn't need to check for authentication before passing control to the controller and (eventually) sending back a resource.

the approach this takes is to have middleware on the server check for auth tokens to make sure the client can call the api. without making you look into the code too much, i'll just give you a basic rundown.

client(requests Auth)->server(approves passes back token)->client(stores token)

LATER:

client(requests api call sends token in request)->server(passes request to middleware that checks token to make sure its kosher)->server(sends back resource and token)->client(uses resource and stores token)

then the whole thing repeats.

as far as whether to have separate apis vs one namespace, i don't have a very strong opinion. it really depends on how you structure your app. if you know in advance what resources will be public, then its probably easy to create a namespaced api.

angular can easily adapt to multiple api calls. you can create services for your public vs private http calls (or whatever way you decide to call the api.)

hope this was somewhat helpful! sorry its not railsy! (but nodejs/express is awesome!)